# Android. Displaying and changing webpage content in my app

Tags: android

Is it possible to open a webpage in my app and change the content of the webpage? Remove/add/modify it's content? Do stuff similar to a browser extension, but done withing an app, in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android Webviews, you can call javascript functions.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

If the webpage is yours, you can add functions specific for the application and that will be called in the webview.

If you're talkign about changing the contents of any webpage. I'm not sure, but i think the only way is to load the files internally, do your modifications and display the local url that you have changed.